# Music player for toddlers

Tags: toddler, music, toys

Could someone recommend a music player for a toddler? The main features I am after are:

1. It should properly play mp3 and have some interface to upload them from a computer
2. It should have either no preloaded music or an easy way to remove it
3. Should be suitable for a 2.5 year old (light, sturdy, easy to use, etc.)

I was trying to find one of these on British Amazon, but I failed miserably.

Comment: You're asking for shopping recommendations, which are off-topic on this site (see our [faq]). If you instead ask a question about _what are useful traits for a toddler MP3 player_ then the question would be useful regardless of what products are currently on the market. (But, to give you a little answer, I would look for a used, cheap [iPod Shuffle](http://www.apple.com/ipodshuffle/).)

Comment: I'd say this is more than a shopping rec, because if you're like our family, music is extremely important and there are almost no acceptable solutions on the market.  The market is Not sufficiently competitive.  I researched every product of the last decade and there is only one I found acceptable.  google "sweetpea mp3". It's from Canada. It's rather expensive and has a few annoying limitations but has been very well worth the money for us. Strengths: durable, plenty of memory, built in speaker, good battery life.  Weaknesses: hard to specify order of songs, setting volume etc. is awkward.

Comment: While I agree that the question as formulated is offtopic, I will give an answer in hopes that the question is improved. highly recommend Sansa Salt Shaker player. It's designed for the kids and I was VERY successful with my kids using it **since the age of 1.5 YO**. Its features include: dual headphones jack for >1 kids, decent enough speaker, AAA batteries, easy controls (as I said, my 1.5YO managed to skip/pause); and pleasant design. It also takes SD card of up to 2GB so plenty of music fits AND you can change the selection anytime. It's also very kid friendly in price - was ~$20.